# Visualizing Heart Rate Data with BarChart

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm looking to visualize heart rate data of a workout for a timeline. Since heart rate data is tracked every ~4-10 seconds during a workout no data is shown for that period. In some cases no heart rate data is tracked for a period of time and there should be no data shown. I'm also looking to visualize the heart zones by color and I found that bar chart allows you to do that.

I'm using the code below to try and visualize what I am trying to achieve and I get the following. Time line is 20 minutes (1200 seconds) and for that period are 214 heart rate data.
[image]

```
        guard let heartRates = heartRates else { return }
        let startInterval = Date.dateFromString(heartRates.first?.startDate)?.timeIntervalSince1970 ?? 0
        
        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
        for i in 0..<heartRates.count {
            if let value = heartRates[i].heartRateToPercentage() {
                let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: (Date.dateFromString(heartRates[i].startDate)!.timeIntervalSince1970 - startInterval), y: value)
                dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
            }
        }
        
        let heartRateBarChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "Heart Rate")
        heartRateBarChartDataSet.colors = colorsForHeartRate(heartRatesData: heartRates)
        heartRateBarChartDataSet.valueFormatter = DigitValueFormatter()
        
        
        heartRateBarChartView.xAxis.enabled = true
        heartRateBarChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        heartRateBarChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        heartRateBarChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.yellow
        heartRateBarChartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
        heartRateBarChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = MinutesValueFormatter()
        heartRateBarChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0
        heartRateBarChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(5, force: true)
        
        heartRateBarChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 40.1
        heartRateBarChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 100.0
        heartRateBarChartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = PercentageValueFormatter()
        heartRateBarChartView.leftAxis.gridLineDashLengths = [2, 2]
        heartRateBarChartView.leftAxis.labelPosition = .outsideChart
        heartRateBarChartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.yellow
        heartRateBarChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
        
        heartRateBarChartView.rightAxis.enabled = true
        heartRateBarChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        heartRateBarChartView.rightAxis.labelPosition = .insideChart
        heartRateBarChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
        
        heartRateBarChartView.legend.enabled = false
        heartRateBarChartView.animate(yAxisDuration: 1.0)
        
        var dataSets = [IChartDataSet]()
        dataSets.append(heartRateBarChartDataSet)
        
        let heartRateChartData = BarChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
        heartRateBarChartView.data = heartRateChartData
    }
```

I've looked at other apps and they are able to visualize the same data in a more "smoother" way - example [image]

I've tried to `BarChartData`s `barWidth` but that doesn't help a lot.
My questions are:

1. Am I using the wrong Chart to try to replicate the same results? Maybe try another type of chart, but I am not sure what would be the best?
2. Are they ways to manipulate data so they show better in the chart?

Thank you.

Comment: you might try using swiftUI it seems they have charts and easy to build - https://www.raywenderlich.com/6398124-swiftui-tutorial-for-ios-creating-charts

Comment: How to make this better is a very difficult question to answer. Could you be more specific maybe with an example of what you want to accomplish? It sounds like you are looking for a different way to show the data but don't know how you want to show it. That is a UX question and not really a coding question.

Comment: is that just a different thickness in the bar?

Comment: @CasperZandbergen Example on what I am trying to accomplish is attached on the question. With the same sample of data there are two visualizations.